# .Replace with Strings and ints in python

Tags: python, replace

```
df['sales'].replace(['sales', 'accounting', 'hr', 'technical', 'support', 'management',
        'IT', 'product_mng', 'marketing', 'RandD'], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], inplace = True)
```

This is the code i'm using, and df is a dataframe with 'sales' as one of the columns.

I'm getting the following error:

[image]

Is there another function that I can use to perform this replacement operation, or am I missing something here?

Thanks

Comment: are you just trying to replace the strings with any int (ie. label encoding?) or specifically the ones you mention. Also, your code worked for me

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension:

```
df['sales'] = [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] if i in ['sales', 'accounting', 'hr', 'technical', 'support', 'management',
    'IT', 'product_mng', 'marketing', 'RandD'] else i for i in df["sales"]]
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with Pandas, but I'm pretty sure you need to use `i in [...]` in your list comprehension rather than `i == [...]`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know what you are trying to accomplish so I give you two choices:

```
df['sales'] = [ index for index, val in enumerate(['sales', 'accounting', 'hr', 'technical', 'support', 'management',
    'IT', 'product_mng', 'marketing', 'RandD'])]
```

OR:

```
df['sales'] = [ index for index, val in enumerate(df['sales'])]
```